# read text into array from a specific character to another specific character.(JavaFx)

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

Hi i have really a hard time to get this right. i hope you can help.
I need to read "Levels" into an array. The levels.txt looks like this.

```
1

    #####
    #   #
    #$  #
  ###  $##
  #  $ $ #
### # ## #   ######
#   # ## #####  ..#
# $  $          ..#
##### ### #@##  ..#
    #     #########
    ####### 
; 2

############
#..  #     ###
#..  # $  $  #
#..  #$####  #
#..    @ ##  #
#..  # #  $ ##
###### ##$ $ #
  # $  $ $ $ #
  #    #     #
  ############
```

So i need to put level1 for example into Array[1] etc.
This is my code that i have.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("levels(2).txt")))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                arr.add(sCurrentLine);
            }
            for (String s : arr) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

So my problem is i don't know how to read each level separately from the "level number" to the ";"

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? Do you get bad behavior? Please [edit] the question and explain the problem.

Comment: i edited the topic

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a suggestion.

I am deliberately not using `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` like you, but the more modern `Path`, `Paths` and `Files` (introduced in Java 7). I read all lines from the file into a list first, that’s done in one call to `Files.readAllLines()`.

I am using nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the levels (1, 2, etc). Inside the loop I am first finding the line with the level number, since any lines before that should just be skipped. Then I am taking lines until the line with the semicolon (if any; or just to the end of the file).

```
    Path input = Paths.get("levels(2).txt");
    List<String> inputLines = Files.readAllLines(input);

    List<List<String>> levels = new ArrayList<>(); // result
    levels.add(null); // put a null at index 0 so first level read will be at index 1
    int levelNo = 1;

    int lineNo = 0;
    while (true) { // this loop will be terminated by break in the middle
        // find level number in a line
        String levelNoAsString = String.valueOf(levelNo);
        while (lineNo < inputLines.size() && ! inputLines.get(lineNo).contains(levelNoAsString)) {
            lineNo++;
        }
        if (lineNo == inputLines.size()) { // no more lines, the end
            break;
        }
        lineNo++; // skip the line with the line no

        // read level
        List<String> currentLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        while (lineNo < inputLines.size() && ! inputLines.get(lineNo).contains(";")) {
            currentLevel.add(inputLines.get(lineNo));
            lineNo++;
        }
        levels.add(currentLevel);

        levelNo++;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void loadLevels(String path){         
 String line;         
 StringBuilder realLine = new StringBuilder();         
 StringBuilder level = new StringBuilder();         
 int cpt = 0;         
 try{             
     BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
     while((line = buff.readLine()) !=null){ 
           realLine.append(line);                 
           while(realLine.length()<30){                     
                realLine.append(" ");                
           }                 
           cpt++;                 
           level.append(realLine);                 
           realLine.setLength(0);                 
           if(cpt%12 == 0){                     
                levels[(cpt/12)-1] = level.toString();
                level.setLength(0);
           }
       }         
 }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
         System.out.println("Pas de fichier");
 }catch(IOException ioe){}
 }
```

I made this when i tried something like this a while ago, that was to read level from 30 char width and 12 of height, hope it could help you.